# ‎‎$‎\langle ‎(‎x_{n}‎)‎,(y_{n})\rangle=\sum_{‎1‎}^{‎\infty‎}\frac{‎‎x_{‎n‎}‎‎\bar{y_{‎n‎}}}{n^{2}}‎$‎‎ defines an inner product

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Check ‎that ‎the ‎formula ‎‎$‎\langle ‎(‎x_{n}‎)‎,(y_{n})\rangle=\sum_{‎1‎}^{‎\infty‎}\frac{‎‎x_{‎n‎}‎‎\bar{y_{‎n‎}}}{n^{2}}‎$‎‎ defines an inner product ‎on ‎‎$‎\ell‎^{‎\infty‎}‎$‎,‎ ‎the space of bounded (complex) sequences. What norm does it produce?

Thanks

Comment: So you check that it satisfies the definition of inner product, and you write down the definition of the norm coming from an inner product.  Which part gave you trouble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

1. Check the definitions of an [inner product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Inner_product). They're straightforward.
2. What is the corresponding [norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Inner_product) (same link, but look just a little bit lower).

If you encounter trouble, I encourage you to include your work in the question and we'll help you from there.